# Use De Morgan's Laws to simplify the following sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Simplify the following sets:

$$ℝ\setminus \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^∞ (-1/n,1/n)\tag1$$

$$\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^∞ (ℝ\setminus[1/n,2+1/n])\tag2$$

For the first problem, I used De Morgan's law, and it equals to $$\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^∞ (ℝ\setminus[-1/n,1/n])\tag2$$
and that is $$\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^∞ ([-∞,-1/n]\bigcup[1/n,+∞])\tag2$$
Well I think that is the set ℝ. But I'm not sure I can't prove it.

For the second problem, using De Morgan's law, it equals

$$ℝ\setminus \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^∞ (1/n,2+1/n)\tag1$$

I don't know what $$\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^∞ (1/n,2+1/n)\tag1$$ is, but I think it's [0,2]. But I can't prove it either way. I'm really sure this question really wants me to simply to an interval on the real number line.

Comment: Is it necessary to use De Morgan's laws in the answer? There are other ways to answer. Also, if you want to get answers, you need to start accepting the best answer to each of your questions.

Comment: I will. I'm really new to this website. Sorry

Comment: I will add more contents now, coz I really have problems typing in math symbols. Didn't intend to do this, guys...

Comment: The [tag:set-theory] tag was removed for a reason, please do not keep re-adding it. If you read the description of the tag, you can see that your question is not related to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:   $A\setminus B = A\cap B^c$

Use this then apply DeMorgan's Laws and Distribution, to simplify the given sets.